# Add sorting and filtering in code

Tags: views, 8

I need to add sorting to a view in code but can't seem to get this to work. This is my code so far.

```
$view = Views::getView('name_of_the_view');
if (!$view) {
  // some irrelevant code to handle a non existing view
}
$view->setDisplay('name_of_the_display');
$view->setArguments([$searchString]);
$view->setCurrentPage($page); 

$view->execute();
```

As far as I know, I need to add `$view->sort` and `$view->filter` before the execute method but don't know what to set this to.

Do I have to pass the name of the sort/filter handler (i.e. 'random') or the class name (i.e. Drupal\views\Plugin\views\sort\Random) or an instance of a sort/filter handler or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was confused by `$view->setExposedInput` saying it accepts `$filters` as argument, but it actually works for sorting as well. So with that function you can set your exposed filters AND sorts

```
$view->setExposedInput([
  'your_filter' => $your_filter_value, //your exposed filter
  'sort_by' => 'your_field', //your exposed sort
  'sort_order' => 'ASC',
]);
```

Use above code before you execute view.

And make sure you exposed your filters and sorts in your view.

Comment: I am actually using this at the moment and it does work. Too bad that the exposed filters have to be set in views rather than in code.

Answer (score 1):

[`Views::getView()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Views.php/function/Views%3A%3AgetView/8.6.x) returns a [`ViewsExecutable`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/class/ViewExecutable/8.6.x) object for which the following public properties are defined:

- [`ViewsExecutable::$filter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/property/ViewExecutable%3A%3Afilter/8.6.x) is an array of objects extending the [`FilterPluginBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21filter%21FilterPluginBase.php/class/FilterPluginBase/8.6.x) class
- [`ViewsExecutable::$sort`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/property/ViewExecutable%3A%3Asort/8.6.x) is an array of objects extending the [`SortPluginBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21sort%21SortPluginBase.php/class/SortPluginBase/8.6.x) class

So, to add a filter in the view you loaded, you should use `$views->filter[] = $filter_object`.

Comment: could you provide a simple example?

Comment: any update on this ? It really looks like the way to go

Comment: setting a value can be done with $view->setHandlerOption() and you pretty much can get all the needed values from the exported view yml file